# Computed not reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I wrote this code to return a list of skills. If the user already has a specific skill, the list-item should be updated to `active = false`.

This is my initial code:

```js
 setup () {

        const user = ref ({
            id: null,
            skills: []
        });

        const available_skills = ref ([
            {value: 'css', label: 'CSS', active: true},
            {value: 'html', label: 'HTML', active: true},
            {value: 'php', label: 'PHP', active: true},
            {value: 'python', label: 'Python', active: true},
            {value: 'sql', label: 'SQL', active: true},
        ]);
 
        const computed_skills = computed (() => {
            let result = available_skills.value.map ((skill) => {
                if (user.value.skills.map ((sk) => {
                    return sk.name;
                }).includes (skill.label)) {
                    skill.active = false;
                }

                return skill;
            });

            return result;
        })


        return {
            user, computed_skills
        }
    },
```

This works fine on the initial rendering. But if I remove a skill from the user doing
`user.skills.splice(index, 1)` the `computed_skills` are not being updated.

Why is that the case?

Comment: Maybe try to avoid splice method, and just use Array.filter?
like: `user.skills = user.skills.filter((skill) => {/* filter logic here */}); `

Comment: I need to splice the item if I want to remove the skill from the user's skill-list, as those items are going to be saved to the database.

Comment: I understood this case, but splice can be done with Array.filter.
You'll reassign it and computed will be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed prop is actually being recomputed when you update `user.skills`, but the mapping of `available_skills` produces the same result, so there's no apparent change.

Assuming `user.skills` contains the full skill set from `available_skills`, the first computation sets all `skill.active` to `false`. When the user clicks the skill to remove it, the re-computation doesn't set `skill.active` again (there's no `else` clause).

```js
let result = available_skills.value.map((skill) => {
   if (
     user.value.skills
       .map((sk) => {
         return sk.name;
       })
       .includes(skill.label)
   ) {
     skill.active = false;
   }
   // ❌ no else to set `skill.active`

   return skill;
});
```

However, your computed prop has a side effect of mutating the original data (i.e., in `skill.active = false`), which [should be avoided](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.html). The mapping above should clone the original `skill` item, and insert a new `active` property:

```js
const skills = user.value.skills.map(sk => sk.name);

let result = available_skills.value.map((skill) => {
  return {
    ...skill,
    active: skills.includes(skill.label)
  }
});
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/computed-prop-dependency-cxqco?file=/src/components/Demo.vue:866-1091)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript user or an object is a refence to the object which is the pointer itself will not change upon changing the underling properties hence the computed is not triggered
kid of like computed property for an array and if that array get pushed with new values, the pointer of the array does not change but the underling reference only changes.

**Work around:**
try and reassign user by shadowing the variable

Answer (score 1):

`slice`  just returns a copy of the changed array, it doesn't change the original instance..hence computed property is not reactive

Try using below code

```
user.skills = user.skills.splice(index, 1);
```